# Get cursor location of a rectangle inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i have a canvas, inside of which i have a board/grid. When a user highlights their mouse over an intersection of the grid, i want it to show where their game peice will go. This worked perfectly fine when the board was the exact size of the canvas. I made it abit smaller by x all the way round.

So as you can see in the picture below, the green shows the canvas and the grid is the board. I put my cursor at the very bottom right corner of the green to show when it triggers. The only one that works fine is the middle one because regardless how big i make the board, the middle will always be the middle.

Any easy fix would just be to make the area with the mouseover event, the dimensions of the board instead of the canvas but the event listener is on the canvas. My code is below the image

[image]

Variables:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("game-canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var boardSize = 13;
var border = canvas.width / 20;
var boardWidth = canvas.width - (border * 2);
var boardHeight = canvas.height - (border * 2);

var cellWidth = boardWidth / (boardSize - 1);
var cellHeight = boardHeight / (boardSize - 1);

var lastX;
var lastY;
```

Mouse over event:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) 
{
    var position = getGridPoint(evt);

    if ((position.x != lastX) || (position.y != lastY))
    {
        placeStone((position.x * cellWidth) + border, (position.y * cellWidth) + border, 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)');         
    }

    lastX = position.x;
    lastY = position.y;     
});
```

Gets the point on the grid and converts that into a number 0 - 13 (in this case)

```
function getGridPoint(evt)
{
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    var x = Math.round((evt.clientX-rect.left)/(rect.right-rect.left)*boardWidth);
    var y = Math.round((evt.clientY-rect.top)/(rect.bottom-rect.top)*boardHeight);

    var roundX = Math.round(x / cellWidth);
    var roundY = Math.round(y / cellHeight);

    return {
      x: roundX,
      y: roundY
    };
}
```

And finally draws the piece on the board:

```
function placeStone(x, y, color)
{
    var radius = cellWidth / 2;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = color;  
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 5;
}
```

I left a couple bits out like how the grid refreshs so its not a string of circles following your mouse and stuff, to keep it as short as i can, im hoping its just a simple asnwer and nobody needs to recreate it but if you do i can include the function that refreshes the grid and draws everything. Thankyou for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the position relative to a box

```
// just as an example w,h are width and height
const box = { x : 10, y : 10, w : 100, h : 100 };
// mouse is the mouse coords and relative to the topleft of canvas (0,0);
var mouse.box = {}
mouse.box.x = mouse.x - box.x;
mouse.box.y = mouse.y - box.y;
```

Negative values for mouse.box x,y and values greater than box width and height have mouse outside.

For more convenience you can get the mouse normalize pos in the box

```
mouse.box.nx = mouse.box.x / box.w;
mouse.box.ny = mouse.box.y / box.h;
```

The coords for nx,ny are in the range 0-1 when inside or on the edge of the box;

If you want to have grid positions then define the grid

```
box.gridW = 10; // grid divisions width
box.gridH = 10; // grid divisions height
```

Then getting the grid pos of mouse

```
mouse.box.gx = Math.floor(mouse.box.nx * box.gridW);
mouse.box.gy = Math.floor(mouse.box.ny * box.gridH);
```

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


const box = { x : 50,y : 10, w : 200, h : 200, gridW : 10, gridH : 10}


function drawGrid(){
    var sx = box.w / box.gridW;
    var sy = box.h / box.gridH;
    var bx = box.x;
    var by = box.y;
    for(var y = 0; y < box.gridH; y ++){
        for(var x = 0; x < box.gridW; x ++){
            ctx.strokeRect(x * sx + bx, y * sx + by,sx,sy);
        }
    }
    if(mouse.box){
      if(mouse.box.nx >= 0  && mouse.box.nx <= 1 &&
      mouse.box.ny >= 0  && mouse.box.ny <= 1){
          ctx.fillRect(mouse.box.gx * sx + bx, mouse.box.gy * sx + by,sx,sy);
      
         }
    }
         
}
const mouse = {};
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",(e)=>{
    mouse.x = e.pageX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY;
});

function updateMouse(){
    if(!mouse.box){
        mouse.box = {};
    }
    mouse.box.x = mouse.x - box.x;
    mouse.box.y = mouse.y - box.y;
    mouse.box.nx = mouse.box.x / box.w;
    mouse.box.ny = mouse.box.y / box.h;
    mouse.box.gx = Math.floor(mouse.box.nx * box.gridW);
    mouse.box.gy = Math.floor(mouse.box.ny * box.gridH);
    var p = 20;
    ctx.fillText("x : " + mouse.x,box.x+box.w+10,p); p+= 14;
    ctx.fillText("y : " + mouse.y,box.x+box.w+10,p); p+= 20;
    ctx.fillText("Box relative",box.x+box.w+10,p); p+= 14;
    ctx.fillText("x : " + mouse.box.x,box.x+box.w+10,p); p+= 14;
    ctx.fillText("y : " + mouse.box.y,box.x+box.w+10,p); p+= 14;
    ctx.fillText("nx : " + mouse.box.nx,box.x+box.w+10,p); p+= 14;
    ctx.fillText("ny : " + mouse.box.ny,box.x+box.w+10,p); p+= 14;
    ctx.fillText("gx : " + mouse.box.gx,box.x+box.w+10,p); p+= 14;
    ctx.fillText("gy : " + mouse.box.gy,box.x+box.w+10,p); p+= 14;
}

function mainLoop(time){
    if(canvas.width !== innerWidth || canvas.height !== innerHeight){ // resize canvas if window size has changed
        canvas.width = innerWidth;
        canvas.height = innerHeight;
    }
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // set default transform
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); // clear the canvas
    updateMouse();
    drawGrid();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

```css
canvas {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0px;
    left : 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas><canvas>
```

Comment: i think i understand what you mean, just shifting the origin(0,0) to the origin of the box instead.
- changed this `var x = Math.round((evt.clientX-rect.left) - border/(rect.right-rect.left)*boardWidth);` so it includes the - border and it seems to be working alright, I have a feeling im missing something but ill find it, thankyou :)